# Plot the results of a cluster analysis on a two-dimensional space

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, seaborn, cluster-analysis

I'm not sure this can be done retrospectively, so I'm not sure my question makes sense.
I used k-means in a 20-dimensional space, resulting in 17 clusters.

I thus obtained a data frame containing the coordinates of the centers, `df_center` (just an example):

```
cluster   x1   x2   x3  ...    x20
   0     0.2  0.1 -0.1  ...  -0.1
   1     ...  ...  ...  ...   ...
  16     ...  ...  ...  ...   ...
```

I also have a data frame with the coordinates of the points and the cluster they belong to, `df_points` (just an example):

```
id_point  x1  x2  x3 ...  x20  cluster
   0      ..  ..  .. ...  ...     0
   1      ..  ..  .. ...  ...    12
   2      ..  ..  .. ...  ...     6
```

I would like to represent, with UMAP or other tools, these data in a two-dimensional space. For example, the centers in black and the other points in different colors according to the cluster to which they belong.

Is it possible to do this starting from these two data frames?

Comment: Well, do you know how to use e.g. UMAP *in general*? Say to get a 2D representation of 20D data. If no: That's the question to ask (or more likely, find an already existing answer to). If yes: Where are you stuck doing this process for `df_center` and `df_points`?

Comment: I don't know how to use UMAP, I read that it is used in this kind of task. I don't know how to plot only the first two coordinates except by truncating the other 18.

Comment: Then I would recommend reading the documentation for some UMAP implementation. Surely there also many UMAP-related questions on StackOverflow. If that fails, then you should make a question that focuses precisely on how to use UMAP on general data, without the added distraction of k-means and plotting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to plot the results of a cluster analysis on a two-dimensional space, using UMAP or other dimensionality reduction techniques. However, you need to apply the same technique to both the centers and the points, and then plot them on the same axes.

For example, using UMAP in Python, you could do something like this:

```py
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import umap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load data frames
df_center = pd.read_csv("df_center.csv")
df_points = pd.read_csv("df_points.csv")

# Extract the coordinates of the centers and the points
X_center = df_center.drop("cluster", axis=1)
X_points = df_points.drop(["id_point", "cluster"], axis=1)

# Apply UMAP to both data sets, using the same parameters
umap_model = umap.UMAP(n_components=2, random_state=42)
X_center_2d = umap_model.fit_transform(X_center)
X_points_2d = umap_model.transform(X_points)

# Add the UMAP coordinates to the data frames
df_center["umap_x"] = X_center_2d[:, 0]
df_center["umap_y"] = X_center_2d[:, 1]
df_points["umap_x"] = X_points_2d[:, 0]
df_points["umap_y"] = X_points_2d[:, 1]

# Plot the centers and the points on the same axes, using different colors and markers
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.scatter(df_points["umap_x"], df_points["umap_y"], c=df_points["cluster"], cmap="tab20", alpha=0.5)
plt.scatter(df_center["umap_x"], df_center["umap_y"], c="black", marker="x", s=100, label="Centers")
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("UMAP 1")
plt.ylabel("UMAP 2")
plt.title("Cluster analysis on a two-dimensional space")
plt.show()
```